# Get documents from one collection that have matching data with another collections document

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to show data on the home screen of my app where if the user who is signed in, has matching data with my "jobs" collection,  then it should display any document which matches the users company name in a flatlist.

The field I am trying to match is "company". I have two collections "users" and "jobs" both contain company fields.

Here is what I have at the moment which is returning all documents in "jobs" collection.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getjobs()
}


getjobs = async () => {
    try {
       const unsubscribe = await firebase.firestore().collection("jobs")
           .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                var _jobs = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach( (doc)=> {
                    const job = doc.data();
                    if(job.company = job.company){
                        _jobs.push({ ...job, id: doc.id });
                    }
                });
                console.log('---------state',this.state);
                this.setState({
                    jobs: _jobs
                })
            });
            this.setState({
                unsubscribe
            })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error cant get jobs', e);
    }
}
```

[image]

My Firstore

Users Collection

[image]

Jobs Collection

[image]

Comment: It's kind of hard to picture what you're trying to do, given that we can't see your database and the documents inside it.  Firestore doesn't have any "join" type operations that query multiple collections, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: You will need to perform a second query to find matching documents in users.  Firestore has no join operations that query multilple collections.

Comment: Ok, I will look into doing this then, thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the jobs and users that match the company? what you can do is to have both queries and then concatenate the result of the queries

Comment: Trying to get all Jobs and then the user who is signed in match the company

Comment: then I would go for the two sepate queries approach

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done, managed to get it working. Thanks for your help

Comment: could you publish your solution here as an answer, I'm sure it can be useful to more people in the future and Iĺl be happy to upvote

Comment: Yeah sure no problem